# What is wrong with my for loop in Array

Tags: javascript

I created an Array:

```
var book = {title: "Ways to Go", pages: 280, bookMark1:"Page 20"};
```

and now I want to loop over the Array and log all properties:

```
function me {
i;
for ( i = 0; i < book.length ; i++ ) { 
console.log(i);
}
};
```

It logs "SyntaxError" but I don't understand where it is

Thanks

Comment: Lot of errors are there.. Are you new to javascript? If so, I would suggest you to read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics).

Comment: try to add befor the for "let i" instead of "i".

Comment: First off, that's not an array

Comment: This is valid JavaScript:

    `var book = {title: "Ways to Go", pages: 280, bookMark1:"Page 20"};
    
    function me() {
      for (var i = 0; i < book.length ; i++ ) { 
        console.log(i);
      }
    }`

Note the parentheses after a function.

What is the meaning of `book.length`? What would be a better name for `i`?

Comment: that's an object. Array uses square brackets like so ['itemOne', 'itemTwo']

Comment: book.length means each items, also property in object